# Generating the hardware delays using timers in STM32F2

Tags: stm32, uart, timer, delay

I am new to this controller STM32F2xx.

Here is my code, this code was given by my senior. It is working, but I don't understand how to calculate the prescaler and ARR value for 1ms delay.

Can anyone help me learn how to configure the timers so they can generate the hardware delays? Please explain in detail.

```
#include "stm32f2xx.h"
#include "stm32f2xx_gpio.h"
#include "stm32f2xx_rcc.h"
#include "stm32f2xx_conf.h"
#include "stm32f2xx_tim.h"
#include "timer.h"

GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;

/* timer3 globalIntrupt  request */
void TIM3_IRQHandler(void)
{

  if(TIM3->SR & TIM_IT_Update)
  {   
    /*clear interrupt flag */
        TIM3->SR = (uint16_t)~TIM_IT_Update;
        GPIO_ToggleBits(GPIOC,GPIO_Pin_5);
    }

}    



int main()
{

    timer3_Init();

    RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOC,ENABLE);


    /* filling the members of the GPIO_InitStructure */
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_5;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_OUT;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_100MHz;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;


    /*configure the GPIOC */
    GPIO_Init(GPIOC,&GPIO_InitStructure);

    while(1)
    {
    }

}

void timer3_Init(void)
{

  RCC->APB1ENR  |= RCC_APB1ENR_TIM3EN;                              /* Enable timer3 clock                */


  TIM3->PSC   = 30000-1;     
  TIM3->ARR   = 2-1;       
  TIM3->EGR   = 0x0001;        
  TIM3->CR1   = 0x0001;     

  NVIC->ISER[TIM3_IRQn >> 0x05] =
                        (uint32_t)0x01 << (TIM3_IRQn & (uint8_t)0x1F);        // enable interrupt
  TIM3->DIER  = 0x0001;                                               // enable intrerrupt

}
```

Comment: When posting code please select the code block and press the `{}` code formatting button. Please make sure that your indentation is correct, that you have adequate comments and then review the post before submitting.

Comment: What part of the reference manual for the part did you not understand?

Answer (score 2):

As usual, the [programming manual](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/51/f7/f3/06/cd/b6/46/ec/CD00225773.pdf/files/CD00225773.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00225773.pdf) is a good place to start. Take a look at page 429:

[image]

So the line:

```
TIM3->PSC   = 30000-1;
```

Sets the prescaler to 30000.

The ARR (auto-reload) register is configured as:

[image]

And the line:

```
TIM3->ARR   = 2-1;
```

Sets the value to 2-1 (which is 1, and I'm not sure why they are doing it that way).

So for the STM32, the actual calculation depends on which clock source is feeding your timers, either APB1 (max 60MHz) or APB2 (max 30MHz). In your case, this is APB1.

So the counter clock frequency is 60,000,000 / 30,000 = 2,000Hz. This gives you a .5ms on the clock for each "count". Since the count has to go from 0->1, this means that your actual frequency is 1ms (and probably why the original programmer typed `2-1`, to illustrate that it needs 2 "periods" to generate an interrupt).